# rostopic publishing strange behavior with remote rosmaster

Tags: ros, remote, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a very strange and annoying problem.
I followed the documentation setup http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup to use a remote rosmaster.
I can see the topic list, ssh from both computers...

**But I have this problem :**

```
node_A is on the computer 1 where roscore is running.
node_B is on the remote computer 2.

node_B listens to a topic published /info by node_A.
```

If I launch node_B then node_A, the callback in node_B which get the message from **/info** is never called.

If I run node_A first, node_B will work as expected.

I noticed that if I do rostopic echo /info in both computers then run node_A. I will see data on computer 1 but not on computer 2.

I did all they asked to check in the documentation so I have no idea where my configuration can be wrong.

Here is the code for the subscriber :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray

def array_callback(array):
    print "Received errors"
    print array.data[0], array.data[1]

rospy.init_node('erros_printer')
rospy.Subscriber("errors", Float32MultiArray, array_callback)

rospy.spin()
```

And the publisher :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
rospy.init_node('errors_sender')
pub = rospy.Publisher("errors", Float32MultiArray)

array = Float32MultiArray()
array.data.append("ok")
array.data.append("hello")

while True:
    pub.publish(array)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214268/rostopic-publishing-strange-behavior-with-remote-rosmaster/) by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 381 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dementor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21822/dementor/) on 2015-07-22**:
Seems less of Configuration issue and more of subscriber publisher problem. Can you give more information on the code for them ?

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2015-07-22**:
I edited my question with a simplified version of my subscriber and publisher nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect your name resolution between hosts is not set up properly.

In particular, I suspect the hostname advertised by computer 2 does not resolve on computer 1.

To confirm this, you can start the nodes on both computers (order doesn't matter), and then try to run `rosnode ping /node_B` on computer 1.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2015-07-23**:
I did rosnode ping errors_printer

I get : rosnode: node is [/errors_printer]
pinging /errors_printer with a timeout of 3.0s
ERROR: connection refused to [http://192.168.1.147:58366/]

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2015-07-24**:
/node_B is visible doing rostopic list on both computers.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-08-08**:
"Connection refused" suggests that the node isn't listening, that it has crashed, or maybe you have a firewall set up which is blocking connections?